# wanted to know how to load test in jmeter or any other tool to test login page with multiple logins at the same time

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

want to know step by step process in jmeter to test multiple users logging in at the same time . please help me with that . I am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

For login event simulation it should be enough to:

1. Record the login via [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
3. Perform correlation of the dynamic parameters if needed. See [How To Use JMeter For Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication) article for details.

For ensuring that all the login requests are executed at exactly the same time:

1. Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) to your Test Plan (better as a child of the Login HTTP Request)
2. Make sure that you provide enough virtual users on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to go through some basic jmeter tutorial. Try [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/index.htm) or any other from your favourite search engine.